# Azure Private DNS with VNET Link not resolving

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway, azure-private-dns

I am setting up a private dns zone in azure because we are moving our API management instance behind an application gateway. i enabled the vnet link between the zone and the significant Vnet, but it does not seem to be resolving, neither from the appgw and also not from a vm in the linked Vnet. What am i missing here?

Comment: Facing the same issue and wondering if there is any way to test the private DNS other than pinging VM's by name.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any resources is registered in private zone. Also it’s worth to check the dns settings on VNET, if it is pointing to default Azure DNS.